# Adding Python 3.7 to Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, conda

My current anaconda only has python 3.8 and 3.9.

```
python                         3.8.5 h05baefb_8_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h3098bc4_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.8 h12cc5a1_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h4b4120c_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hf1b0709_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.2 hcbd9b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge
```

This is what it output when I enter `conda search --full-name python`

Now I want to install tensorflowjs but for that I need tensorflow, but `pip install tensorflow` gives me this error
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

My python version is 3.8.8 in my virtual environment but I think I need to be in a lower version, but when try to install python 3.7 using `conda install -c anaconda python=3.7` it gives me this

```
  - python=3.7

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I have no idea how to get python 3.7 in my conda, please help!

Answer (score 2):

As [merv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570918/merv) pointed out in his comment:

> OP is on osx-arm64 platform. There are only Python v3.8 and v3.9
> builds for that.

When you type `conda search python` in your terminal, you will see that the Conda-forge channel only supports Python versions down until 3.8.5.

[This article](https://blog.balasundar.com/install-older-versions-of-python-using-miniconda-on-mac-m1) shows how to install older versions using miniconda. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem... I deleted Anaconda completely from my mac using https://nektony.com/mac-app-cleaner, my channels were completely broken but now I can use previous Python version. Also the reason why I think they were broken was because I did follow a tutorial on installing the tensorflow fork for M1 Macs, that might've broken something.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
conda create -n "testenv" python=3.7 -c conda-forge
```

this works for me with conda version `4.9.2`.

For info, conda-forge can sometimes provides alternatives when conda becomes limited.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried what you said and it sadly gave me the exact same output of "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:" (same as in my question). I'm also on conda verison 4.9.2 so no idea why this won't work :( For some reason my channels just don't allow me to choose python 3.7

Comment: This is probably because conda-forge is not added to your channels. Run `conda config --append channels conda-forge` then try the command again.

Comment: Just tried that and it said "Warning: 'conda-forge' already in 'channels' list, moving to the bottom", so I think I already have it, ran your line again and it gave me the same problem. In your anaconda navigator when you go to the environments tab and create a new environment, does the python version include 3.7? Mine only has the option for 3.8, and I can't even install 3.7 apparently.

Comment: When I listed all available versions I also didn't get version 3.7 before. Try restoring free channels searching by prepending the following to the install command `CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1`  ... I assume you are on a *nix system. If on Windows I believe it's `SET CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1` and then rerun install command. If you want to only try this on a single environment try: `conda config --env --set restore_free_channel true`

Comment: If the above also doesn't work, then please output the results of: `conda config --show channels`

Comment: So i'm in a conda environment right now and I ran the line "conda config --env --set restore_free_channel true", you said prepend it to the install command but I'm not exactly sure which install command you are talking about. I just ran the line and tried the same things I've tried before and its giving me the same error, could you clarify further sorry (I'm on mac btw)

Comment: "conda config --show channels"
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge

Comment: It's not a free channel issue. OP is on **osx-arm64** platform. There are only Python v3.8 and v3.9 builds for that.